# Failure handling in a Parser function

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators, trifecta

I'm learning Parser Combinators with [Trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-2) library. I was introduced to [Alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) typeclass and it's <|> function.

I got a Parser function in my code whose definition is

```
fractionOrDecimal :: Parser DoubleOrRational
fractionOrDecimal =
        (Left <$> try parseDecimal)                  -- A
    <|> (Right <$> try parseFraction)                -- B
    <|> (fail  "Expected Fraction or Decimal.")      -- Err
```

which attempts to parse the input as either decimal or fraction and fail if nothing worked. Is this approach correct or should I encode the failure *(fail)* differently rather than being part of the <|> operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Failure is encoded by the absence of a successful parser. Trifecta will track the expected tokens for you, but you do have to tell it what they are called using `<?>`. So you would do

```hs
fractionOrDecimal :: Parser DoubleOrRational
fractionOrDecimal =
        (Left  <$> try parseDecimal  <?> "Decimal")
    <|> (Right <$> try parseFraction <?> "Fractional")
```

We now get errors like this:

```
>>> parseTest fractionalOrDecimal "neither fractional nor decimal"
error: expected: Decimal, Fractional
neither fractional nor decimal<EOF> 
^
```

Comment: Thanks. TIL <?> function.